# Trigger to update specific row from table SAP HANA

Tags: hana, hana-studio

I am trying to create a trigger on Hana Studio to update a given registry (column `F2` from table `T2`) when an update happens in table `T1`.
A row from `T1` is referenced in table `T2` with the column `X1` (that is, `X1` in `T1` is equal to `X2` on `T2`).

What I would like to do is to get the value from the column `X1` from table `T1` (that is the table that's being updated) and use it as a where clause to know which row I should update on table `T2`.

This is my trigger (or what I would like it to do):

```
create trigger TRIGGERNAME
after update on "SCHEMANAME.T1" for each row
begin
update "SCHEMANAME.T2" 
set F2 = "MY NEW VALUE" 
where X2 = X1
end;
```

Problem is `X1` is a column from my updated row. Is there a way to access data from the updated row on my trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `REFERENCING new row as ... | old row as ...` clause.
Details on this can be found in the [reference documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20d5a65575191014946db96aaedbef5b.html).

A simple example:

**Table setup**

```
create table one (ID int primary key, F2 nvarchar(100));
create table two (ID int primary key, F2 nvarchar(100));

insert into one values (1, 'Bla');
insert into one values (2, 'Blupp');

insert into two values (1, 'Bla');
insert into two values (2, 'Blupp');
```

**Create the trigger**

```
create trigger "ONE_TO_TWO"
    after update 
    on "ONE"   
    referencing new row as new, old row as old 
    for each row
begin
    update "TWO" t
    set "F2" = :new."F2"
    where t."ID" = :old."ID";
end;
```

**Check current data**

```
select 
      one.id as ONE_ID, one.f2 as ONE_F2
    , two.id as TWO_ID, two.f2 as TWO_F2
from 
    one full outer join two
    on one.id = two.id;

/*
ONE_ID  ONE_F2  TWO_ID  TWO_F2
1       Bla     1       Bla   
2       Blupp   2       Blupp 
*/
```

**Update a record and check data again**

```
update "ONE" 
    set "F2" = 'CHANGED THIS'
    where "ID" = 1;

/*
ONE_ID  ONE_F2          TWO_ID  TWO_F2      
1       CHANGED THIS    1       CHANGED THIS
2       Blupp           2       Blupp       
*/
```

While using a trigger may often appear like a good approach, I recommend reconsidering what this is going to be used for and if there aren't any better approaches to handle the requirements. Triggers per se always introduce "magic" into the data model since they change the semantics of normal statements - your `UPDATE` suddenly updates multiple tables - without being obvious to the  DB user. 
In fact, only if one actively looks for triggers there's a chance that the impact they have on how the database 'behaves' is understood.

For multi-table updates, a stored procedure may that handles the dependencies may be the more obvious and better maintainable way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Seems like the right path, but I still have one more doubt. I would like the trigger to fire only when a given column from table ONE is updated, not just on any update on table ONE. Is is possible to set a specific column on the " after update on "ONE" " statement? For example, if I care only about the F2 column updates on table ONE, is it possible to set the statement to " after update on "ONE"."F2" "?

Comment: Yes, the linked documentation shows how one can limit the trigger action to specific columns or exclude specific columns. If you update the question with this additional requirement then I’ll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I believe you answered the question I asked. Thank you. Since I have doubts that differ from what I asked, I asked a different question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297810/conditional-update-on-hana-studio-sql-script-trigger

Thank you for your time.