# Conditional update on HANA Studio (SQLScript) trigger

Tags: hana, sql-scripts, hana-sql-script, hana-studio

I would like to write a trigger on HANA Studio using SQLScript to update `COLUMN_E` from `TABLE2` when `COLUMN_B` from `TABLE1` is updated to a specific value (let's say, 100).
Rows from table 1 are referenced in table 2 with the first column (`ID`).

I have two example tables:

```
    TABLE1:
      ID    | COLUMN_B| COLUMN_C
   _________|_________|_________
       1    |    0    |    1
    ________|_________|_________
       2    |    0    |    1
    ________|_________|_________
       3    |    0    |    1


    TABLE2:
      ID    | COLUMN_E| COLUMN_F
    ________|_________|________
       1    |    Y    |    X
    ________|_________|_________
       2    |    Y    |    X
    ________|_________|_________
       3    |    Y    |    X
```

I wrote the following code:

```
create trigger "UPDATE_TABLES"
    after update of "COLUMN_B" on "TABLE1"
    referencing new row as new, old row as old
    for each row 
begin
    update "TABLE2"
    set "COLUMN_E" = 'my new value'
    where :old."COLUMN_B" = '100' and "TABLE1"."ID" = :old."ID";
end;
```

When I set `TABLE1.COLUMN_B` on row 1 to 100, I expect the code to change `TABLE2.COLUMN_E` to "my new value" on row 1, but nothing happens. Could anyone point what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the UPDATE statement in the trigger code should be slighly different as follows

```
create trigger "UPDATE_TABLES"
    after update of "COLUMN_B" on "TABLE1"
    referencing new row as new, old row as old
    for each row 
begin
    update "TABLE2"
    set "COLUMN_E" = 'my new value'
    where :new."COLUMN_B" = '100' 
    and TABLE2.ID = :old."ID";
end;
```

Otherwise, I get syntax error while creating the trigger 
Could you please verify?

Comment: You  are absolutely right. I just mistaked table 1 for table 2 on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake. I wanted the column_e value to change on changes on values from column_b, but I was actually tracking the old values from column_b. Corrected it to:

```
create trigger "UPDATE_TABLES"
    after update of "COLUMN_B" on "TABLE1"
    referencing new row as new, old row as old
    for each row 
begin
    update "TABLE2"
    set "COLUMN_E" = 'my new value'
    where :new."COLUMN_B" = '100' and "TABLE1"."ID" = :old."ID";
end;
```

and it worked!